# Problems with URL get parameters

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an Android application that will fetch content from Internet. The URL consists of some query parameters with String values. The problem is when I'm trying to use a string value that contains some spaces it doesn't work. But, others work fine. This is the code below that I use to get content with get method.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/fetch.php?title="+someStringValue);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
while((temp=br.readLine())!=null){
    data+=temp;
}
```

The problem is I cannot use a spaced string for the variable `someStringValue`. I know that there are some encoding problems, but how can I resolve it? **Also, what's the best way to read data data from a URL using GET method?**

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) can help you

Comment: Buffered reader is the best way to read data from an text based input stream.

Comment: Have a look at [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/).

Comment: @AnubianNoob I used BufferedReader only..

Comment: @Gowtham exactly I'm saying you are correct :)

Comment: you need to use URLEncoder

Comment: @AnubianNoob :) I read that here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7213417/2277817

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: @njzk2 no, it doesn't work; have a look at the link I provided above

Comment: @fge : no. URLEncoder is the proper way to encode name value pairs, I don't see a/ why I would use an extra library if I don't need something that URLEncoder can't do, b/ why you would say that it does not work.

Comment: @fge I took a look at the link you specified but it seems to be a bit complex.

Comment: @AnubianNoob : I disagree. You don't know that there are line breaks, for one, and you loose the line break character.

Comment: @Gowtham maybe, but it is reliable! All tests from the URI template test suite pass

Comment: @njzk2 again, look at the link I provided

Comment: @fge : If URLEncoder does not suite you, may be `Uri.encode` would?

Comment: @njzk2 no idea what this class is... But there is indeed a simple thing to do: build using the `URI` constructor...

Comment: @fge : `android.net.Uri`, quite standard

Comment: @njzk2 except if you don't use Android

Comment: I'm using this code for Android

Comment: @fge: which you do if you read the tag associated to the question.

Comment: @fge, also, according to W3C `Within the query string, the plus sign is reserved as shorthand notation for a space.` Hence the `+` is valid as a replacement for ` `, hence URLEncoder does what it's name says (I mostly use Apache UrlEncodedUtils included in android)

Comment: @njzk2 this is not what RFC 3986 says (section 3.4)

Comment: @fge there is nothing relevant to that matter in section 3.4

Comment: @kiruwka : no, I'd like to get to the bottom of this. `+` is used a lot to replace space in urls, yet @fge seems quite certain it is not supposed to. I am curious to have a definite answer one way or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit :**

*fge* is actually right, `URLEncoder` will give you "+" instead of "%20" for spaces.

Since you are on android I recommend simple alternative :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.comfetch.php?title=" +
    Uri.encode(someStringValue));
```

Using [Uri.encode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

OK, so, before a common misconception makes it way in there...

**`URLEncoder` does not work.**

`URLEncoder` encodes data for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. And this is not what is used to escape URI query fragments. For one, the set of escaped characters is different; and of course there is the problem that this method encodes spaces with `+`.

Here are three solutions...

---

Use the `URI` constructor:

```
// Put title string UNESCAPED; the constructor will escape for you
final URL url = new URI("http", null, "www.example.com", -1, "/fecth.php",
    "title=yourtitle", null).toURL();
```

---

If you are using Guava (15+) then you may use [this class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html#line.125), which also does the job:

```
final Escaper escaper = UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper();
final String escapedTitle = escaper.escape("yourtitlestring");

final URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/fetch.php?title="
    + escapedTitle);
```

---

The bazooka to kill a fly: URI templates. [Using this library](https://github.com/fge/uri-template):

```
final URITemplate template 
    = new URITemplate("http://www.example.com/fetch.php?title={title}");

final VariableMap varmap = VariableMap.newBuilder()
    .addScalar("title", "yourtitlehere")
    .build();

final URL url = template.toURL(varmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the spaces with the code "%20". URL encoding replaces a space with this code.

To read data I usually use the BufferedReader but like this:

```
URL url = new URL("URL");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String s, response = "";
while ((s = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response += s;
}
```

Comment: That's the only fix to the code? Or any other changes?

Comment: @Gowtham depends on how "complex" your parameters can be; look at the library I pointed to in the comments. Also, if you use Guava 15+, there are escaping classes you can use

Comment: @user432 does not work! `URLEncoder` is for form data, NOT URI query parameters

Comment: For the spaces problem I think that's enough

Comment: Why you're adding HttpURLConnection to it. Does it makes a difference?

Comment: url.openConnection() is a more powerful function, it's usually recommended instead of url.openStream()